# How can I dynamically choose which column to join on in SQL?

Tags: t-sql, join

Say I have the following table in SQL Server (2008):

```
Person

|PersonID|NickName|FirstName|LastName|
|1       |Jim     |James    |Leahy   |
|2       |Mike    |Michael  |Ross    |
|3       |Bob     |Robert   |Helberg |
```

I want to know if the following is possible in SQL. I have a main table and I would like to find matches on another table based on the `NickName` and `FirstName` columns. However, I want the columns to be joined to in a specific order.

I want to join on the first column from above (`NickName` or `FirstName`) which will match the identifier in the table below

```
|Identifier|PersonId|
|Jim       |1       | <- should return PersonId = 1
|Michael   |2       | <- should return PersonId = 2
```

So if there is a match on `NickName` then choose the row. If there is no match on `NickName` then look at `FirstName`.

Is there any way I can query on `NickName` and `FirstName` columns in a particular order?

I don't think `COALESCE` will work since we are not guaranteed that any of the columns will be `NULL` - we only know that a match may not occur on the column instead.

*Please let me know if you need clarification; I may not have worded this well.*

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? If you are using Sql server then you can use `COALESCE` here is the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).  **Sample Sql Script**`Select COALESCE(NickName, Firstname) from Person`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if `COALESCE` will work since, for example, the `NickName` column is not NULL - it is "Mike" but it contains a match with the second table on the `FirstName` "Michael"

Comment: `Select Identifier, PersonId from Person, tblIdentifier where Person.NickName = tblIdentifier.Identifier union Select Identifier, PersonId from Person, tblIdentifier where Person.Firstname= tblIdentifier.Identifier` I am not sure this is right solution but you can use **union** to reach your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the schema of main table I assume it has `Identifier varchar(100)` field, which can contain either `nickname` or `firstname`. In this case the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53fac/7) should look like:

```
select m.identifier, 
PersonId = isnull(p1.PersonID,p2.PersonID)
from maintable m
left join persons p1 on p1.nickname = m.identifier
left join persons p2 on p2.firstname = m.identifier
```